# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' : clustering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do a clustering. I'm doing with pandas and sklearn.

```
import pandas
import pprint
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

dataset = pandas.read_csv('text.csv', encoding='utf-8')

dataset_list = dataset.values.tolist()


vectors = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectors.fit_transform(dataset_list)

clusters_number = 20

model = KMeans(n_clusters = clusters_number, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 300, n_init = 1)

model.fit(X)

centers = model.cluster_centers_
labels = model.labels_

clusters = {}
for comment, label in zip(dataset_list, labels):
    print ('Comment:', comment)
    print ('Label:', label)

try:
    clusters[str(label)].append(comment)
except:
    clusters[str(label)] = [comment]
pprint.pprint(clusters)
```

But I have the following error, even though I have never used the lower():

```
File "clustering.py", line 19, in <module>
    X = vetorizer.fit_transform(dataset_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1381, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 869, in fit_transform
self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 232, in <lambda>
return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I don't understand, my text (text.csv) is already lowercase. And I at no time called lower()

**Data:**

> hello wish to cancel order thank you confirmation
>
> hello would like to cancel order made today store house world
>
> dimensions bed not compatible would like to know how to pass cancellation refund send today cordially
>
> hello possible cancel order cordially
>
> hello wants to cancel order request refund
>
> hello wish to cancel this order can indicate process cordially
>
> hello seen date delivery would like to cancel order thank you
>
> hello wants to cancel matching order good delivery n ° 111111
>
> hi would like to cancel this order
>
> hello order product store cancel act doublon advance thank you cordially
>
> hello wishes to cancel order thank you kindly refund greetings
>
> hello possible cancel order please thank you in advance forward cordially

Comment: try `vectors = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False)`

Comment: Can you try changing the name of your script from clustering.py to my_clustering.py ?

Comment: Didn't work, I have another error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Also change the name of the csv text file to my_text.csv

Comment: can you add the data ?

Comment: How many columns do you have in `text.csv`? If more than one column, then you cannot use TfidfVectorizer on it.

Comment: I only have one column (a few thousand long sentences)

Comment: Can you confirm that `pd.read_csv` is returning single column data. Try `print(len(dataset.columns))`. Can you show a part of your actual test.csv (not examples of sentences), which I can load the same way you have using `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: For print(len(dataset.columns)), my result is 1 (I have 60,000 rows in my dataset). I edited my comment showing a part of my dataset (there are no white lines, I just don't know how to edit a dataset here). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
dataset_list = dataset.values.tolist()
```

You see, `dataset` is a pandas DataFrame, so when you do `dataset.values`, it will be converted to a 2-d dataset of shape (n_rows, 1) (Even if the number of columns are 1). Then calling `tolist()` on this will result in a list of lists, something like this:

```
print(dataset_list)

[[hello wish to cancel order thank you confirmation],
 [hello would like to cancel order made today store house world],
 [dimensions bed not compatible would like to know how to pass cancellation refund send today cordially]
 ...
 ...
 ...]]
```

As you see, there are two square brackets here.

Now `TfidfVectorizer` only requires a list of sentences, not lists of list and hence the error (because `TfidfVectorizer` assumes internal data to be sentences, but here it is a list).

So you just need to do this:

```
# Use ravel to convert 2-d to 1-d array
dataset_list = dataset.values.ravel().tolist()
```

OR

```
# Replace `column_name` with your actual column header, 
# which converts DataFrame to Series
dataset_list = dataset['column_name'].values).tolist()
```