# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' in term frequency inverse document frequency

Tags: python, nlp

I found lots of post in stack overflow related to this problem. I tried those but still getting the same error.
I'm using python 3.7 & wrote following code for my urdu data set

```
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()

x=Tfidf_vect.fit(df['final'])
```

But got error message `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` Then I found this stack overflow post

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' : clustering
```

. It's suggesting TfidfVectorizer only requires a list of sentences
So I follow the steps mentioned in solution & modify the code & use following code

```
vectors = TfidfVectorizer()
dataset_list=df['final'].values.ravel().tolist()
X = vectors.fit_transform(dataset_list)
```

Sample data set is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497681/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-lower-clustering)
Still the same error message.Can you suggest me the steps to correc?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input data

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include samples of your input data in your question, not as a link or picture, to make a [mcve]. It's highly relevant to know exactly what _your_ data (`df`) looks like right before you call the transformer on it. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fit_transform method accepts an iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects as an argument. There may overlooked items in your input data. Be sure all items are str. Check via below snippet.

```
False in map((lambda x: type(x) == str), df['final'])
```